# Prevent OOM killer inside guest in LXC

Tags: process, swap, kill, lxc, out-of-memory

I have a python program `myprogram.py`. I realized that my python program is being killed due to Out Of Memory (OOM). But, I noticed also that my VPS is inside LXC and has swap 1GB, when the memory full (I checked with `htop`), it didn't utilize the swap memory even though my VPS has built-in swap. I don't have permission to change the kernel configuration, `vm.swappiness`. But I do realize that there is `cgroups` word in `df` command, perhaps it can help me to prevent OOM Killer from killing `myprogram.py`.

Here is cgroups memory:

```
cgroup.clone_children  memory.kmem.failcnt             memory.kmem.tcp.limit_in_bytes      memory.max_usage_in_bytes        memory.move_charge_at_immigrate  memory.stat            notify_on_release
cgroup.event_control   memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes      memory.kmem.tcp.max_usage_in_bytes  memory.memsw.failcnt             memory.numa_stat                 memory.swappiness      system.slice
cgroup.procs           memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes  memory.kmem.tcp.usage_in_bytes      memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes      memory.oom_control               memory.usage_in_bytes  tasks
memory.failcnt         memory.kmem.slabinfo            memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes          memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes  memory.pressure_level            memory.use_hierarchy   user.slice
memory.force_empty     memory.kmem.tcp.failcnt         memory.limit_in_bytes               memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes      memory.soft_limit_in_bytes       my_python_program
root@mydom:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory#
```